# In Java, is it worthy to store a field from another class in a field in my class?

Tags: java, performance, field

Suppose I have a java class (which we will call `ThatClass`) with a lot of static final fields (none of them value fields though) and suppose that I access a lot of those fields, a lot of times each, from methods in a class which we will call `ThisClass`. Considering a situation where both memory use and performance are critical, is it worthy to store the static final fields from `ThatClass` that are used inside methods of `ThisClass` as fields in `ThisClass`?

Example:

```
public class ThatClass
{
    public static final Foo field1 = new Foo();
    public static final Foo field2 = new Foo();
    public static final Foo field3 = new Foo();
}


//implementation A
public class ThisClass
{
    public ThisClass()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            Bar(ThatClass.field1, ThatClass.field2, ThatClass.field3);
        }
    }

    public void Bar(Foo arg1, Foo arg2, Foo arg3)
    {
        // do something.
    }

    /* imagine there are even other methods in ThisClass that need to access the
     * fields of ThatClass.
     */
}
```

now this other implementation of `ThisClass`

```
//implementation B
public class ThisClass
{
    private final Foo myField1;
    private final Foo myField2;
    private final Foo myField3;

    public ThisClass()
    {
        myField1 = ThatClass.field1;
        myField2 = ThatClass.field2;
        myField3 = ThatClass.field3;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            Bar(myField1, myField2, myField3);
        }
    }

    public void Bar(Foo arg1, Foo arg2, Foo arg3)
    {
        // do something.
    }

    /* imagine there are even other methods in ThisClass that need to access the
     * fields of ThatClass.
     */
}
```

I know I wouldn't need to pass the three fields as arguments for the method `Bar` in implementation B, but for the sake of this discussion, imagine that was a necessity.

Questions:

1. Is there any difference regarding performance between the two implementations? Is B faster than A?
2. Regarding memory cost, B demands more memory than A? I'd imagine it does, but just a little more (one extra reference for each extra field in B. Each reference being the size of an int, right?)

Thanks!

Comment: Implement a test and measure it. The overhead for accessing a static field *might* include a cache miss, but in practice I doubt you'd see any measurable benefit

Comment: If anything, duplicating the fields in two places will reduce performance (due to cache misses) and increase memory use. Access to a static field takes the same amount of time whether it is in your class or not.

Comment: Where do you expect the difference in performance to come from? You are copying the same reference to another address, how can that help?

Comment: I would also add that the second method will likely reduce code clarity.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! So I'm going with Implementation A. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to what Russell said.  Furthermore, having the fields defined in two places violates the  [DRY principle (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  You give a very trivial example, but imagine you need to change the definition of one of those static fields.  With the second implementation you have to update the code twice - assuming you remember you have two definitions of the same field.